# Writing variable additions and custom outcomes in Python

Tags: python, variables, char

Im trying to create and run a program that allows the user to insert 2 drug names and receive their outcome. This is what my code looks like so far, yet I cant figure out the syntax error or if it's the best way to go about my plan

```
a = int(input("A.C"))
B = int(input("Opioid"))
sum = a + b
print("Incompatible, increased death rate", sum)
```

Comment: What is the syntax error you get?

Comment: Show the full traceback of the error as properly formatted text in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the variable name(b), also I added the new line when user wants to enter a value. I used fprint to print the output.

```
a = int(input("A.C \n") )
b = int(input("Opioid \n"))
sum = a+b
print(f'Incompatible, increased death rate, {sum}')
```

Answer (score 1):

In your code, you make an assignment to `B` and then attempt to read from `b`. Those are two different variables. All names in Python are case-sensitive.